How to use data binding correctly in ASP.NET Razor page which updates the model in a handler?
I have the following two textarea, and a handler which supposed to copy the InputText to OutputText. However the OutputText binded value in the textarea keeps its original value.
When I press the Generate button on my Page, the handler correctly called, correctly assigns the new value "Processed: Input1", then on the form I see the correct expected value "Processed: Input1" in <div>@Model.Data.OutputText</div>, however in the output text textarea I see the original unchanged value, I do not understand why. I would like to see here also the current updated value of the model.
Question:
How to bind correctly model values, and reflect the model changes when using handlers?
Issue and source code:

<form method="post">
   <div>
      <label for="inputText">Input Text:</label>
      <textarea id="inputText" asp-for="Data.InputText" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
   </div>

   <div>@Model.Data.OutputText</div>
   <div>
      <label for="outputText">Output Text:</label>
      <textarea id="outputText" asp-for="Data.OutputText" class="form-control" rows="5" readonly></textarea>
   </div>

    <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="Generate" class="btn btn-primary">Generate</button>

</form>


public class ColorPickerModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public PageModelData Data { get; set; } = new()
    {
        InputText = "Input1",
        OutputText = "Output1"
    };

    public void OnGet()
    {
    }

    public void OnPostGenerate()
    {
        Data.OutputText = $"Processed: {Data.InputText}";
    }
}


This is a kind of a fucked up gotcha. The TagHelper asp-for="Data.OutputText" does not in fact refer to the PageModel’s Data property, but to an entry in the its ModelState dictionary.
Since your output textarea doesn’t need to be part of the form in the first place, I would just skip the TagHelper business and write
<textarea id="outputText" class="form-control" rows="5" readonly>@Model.Data.OutputText</textarea>

Honestly I would prefer writing my own HTML in general, but that’s just me.
You could also do this if you really hate HTML:
@Html.TextArea(Model.Data.OutputText, Model.Data.OutputText, 5, 0, new { @class = "form-control", required = false, @readonly = true, id = "outputText" })


It would bind both the value of PageModel and ModelState dic(to keep the value after the post request),the value in ModelState has a higher priority
You could remove  the value of Data.OutputText in modelstate dictionary  as below:
 public void OnPostGenerate()
 {
     Data.OutputText = $"Processed: {Data.InputText}";
     ModelState.Remove("Data.OutputText");
 }

Result:

And  model binding depends on "name" property of the input,it should be:
<textarea name="Data.OutputText" class="form-control" rows="5" readonly>@Model.Data.OutputText</textarea>

